# Oracle constraint within a sequence

Tags: oracle, constraints, sequence, oracle12c, ddl

I'm trying to create a constraint on a column that it must be within a sequence (i.e. `col_name < seq.maxval`)

I tried to use a regular constraint, but the column doesn't have anything to tie to - it is just a sequence, not a column in a table.

Checks can't reference any kind of query, so I don't think that would work either.

```
ALTER TABLE STE_FILECOLL ADD (
  CONSTRAINT STE_FC_CLFC_REF_STEF_IDFILE
  FOREIGN KEY (CLFILECOLL) 
  REFERENCES ????
  ENABLE VALIDATE
);
```

I expect there is a way to make sure that the values of a column are within a sequence, but an hour of reading documentation and duckduckgoing have been fruitless, so I turn to here.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you want to just use the sequence to populate the column, you can do that easily enough.  Or create a foreign key that references a table whose column is already populated from that sequence.  But given the realities of multi-user environments, even defining the maximum value of a sequence can be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In `Oracle DB` version `12c`, a sequence's next value might be set as default for a column :*

```
create table STE_FILECOLL
(
  col0     int default seq1.nextval not null,
  col_name int
);
```

*and then check constraints might be added to provide the desired condition as :*

```
alter table STE_FILECOLL
  add constraint STE_CC_CLFC_REF_STEF_IDFILE
  check (col_name < col0);
```

Comment: We recently upgraded to 12c, so this is an option now that I didn't realize existed. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisBurrus Take it easy.

Answer (score 1):

The only sequence pseudocolumns are `nextval` and `currval`, so you can't use that kind of syntax. Inline constraints are pretty limited. I think your best bet is to use a trigger.

```
[...]
select as.maxval into l_maxval from all_sequences where sequence_name = 'my_sequence';

if :new.col_name > l_maxval then
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'too big' );
end if;
```